# What is the real world performance overhead that comes with containerization?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, architecture, microservices

Proponents say performance cost is negligible and that trade off comes with benefits such as scalability and uptime etc. What I'm trying to get at is when in a real world scenario would container orchestration be justifiable, and what would be the best way to go about it? What are the most common issues with such high traffic? (with an example tech stack preferably) I read recently that prime video had cut costs by 90% by changing the part of the architecture to a monolith style. It's hard to imagine, because I've containerized parts of apps that don't receive anywhere near the number of requests between services - so this is more of a in practice question. Thanks.

not really a problem, would like to ask people with practice experience for advice.

Comment: Containers use namespaces, so there is virtually no execution overhead. Containerized processes run the same way standalone processes run. There may be some overhead due to networking, which is usually negligible,

Answer (score 1):

Everything is a trade-off in the Application world. Being said the choice of System design whether it's a Monolith or MicroService way is a very project-specific decision.

You are correct on the Prime video part where they saved tons of $ by switching back to good old monolith Architecture. Being said that is it that easy? no really. Imagine what level of effort was gone into designing a monolith that fulfills the majority of the requirements regarding scale, and availablity needed by the team.

Answering your question I think the use/application of container orchestration is justifiable in two major scenarios. first, your application fits well with what container orchestration has to offer. and other and most important one is your or your team is capable of understanding and managing complex builds and orchestration-based tools like let's say Kubernetes. I explicitly mentioned the reason in two cases I have seen major blunders happening due to lack of proper understanding.

Lastly here are a few lists of overhead/challenges due to containerization:

1. Abstraction between host and container which brings additional overhead to managing them
2. As pointed out by Burak containers have their own networking IF. managing that is a bit overhead rather than running the app on the host itself.
3. Docker-App isolation that too in an abstracted way of operating processes which we discussed in point 1.
4. Distributes logging, Assuming container pods/docker instances come on and off as per load requirements. logging/log archiving is a challenging task.

Hope this helps.